# How to explode nested struct with varying schema for each row in Pyspark of AWS Glue

Tags: amazon-web-services, pyspark, etl, aws-glue

I have a Pyspark data frame with the following schema (printSchema) that looks like this:

```
    root
 |-- accountid: string (nullable = true)
 |-- foodlist: struct (nullable = true)
 |    |-- Tokyo: struct (nullable = true)
 |    |    |-- latte: integer (nullable = true)
 |    |    |-- smoothie: integer (nullable = true)
 |    |-- Moscow: struct (nullable = true)
 |    |    |-- orangejuice: integer (nullable = true)
 |    |    |-- latte: integer (nullable = true)
 |    |    |-- smoothie: integer (nullable = true)
 |    |    |-- donuts: integer (nullable = true)
```

Each row can have different cities and within each city the food items and their numbers will vary.

I want to change it to something like this , So for each foodlist.{city_name}.{food_type} within each row , it will create a single row:

accountid | city-name | food-type | number_of_orders

I am using AWS Glue to do this ETL. I have tried Glue relationalize class as well as Pyspark functions like explode but neither gives what I want.

Comment: how do you evaluate `food-type`?

Comment: food-type from my example is latte/smoothie/orangejuice etc